# Image of a sequence with limit point x

Tags: real-analysis

If $f$ is a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$, is it true that $x$ is a limit point of $x_1,x_2, \dots$implies that $f(x)$ is a limit point of $f(x_1)$,$f(x_2)$,$\dots$?

I am tempted to answer yes due to the fact that $f$ is continuous. Since $x$ is a limit point we have that $|x_i -x| <\epsilon$ for infinitely many $x_i$ in the sequence and $\epsilon >0$. 
Then by the definition of continuity there exists $\delta > 0$ such that

$|x_i -x| <\epsilon$ implies $|f(x_i)-f(x)| < \delta$.

And so $f(x)$ must be a limit point as there are infinitely many $f(x_i)$ clustered around $f(x)$.

Am I missing anything crucial/subtle?

Comment: In fact, it is equivalent to continuity, so long as you replace sequences by nets. Or if you're in a first countable space, sequences suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got it. In fact, this property is often more useful than the epsilon-delta definition

Comment: Pressed submit too soon and it easier to add a comment. This is true in any metric space and if some countability conditions hold, then this is equivalent to continuity